# Efficient way to delete values from hashmap object

Tags: java, hashmap

I have HashMap object contains a key `x-y-z` with corresponding value `test-test1-test2`.

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
map.put("x-y-z","test-test1-test2");
map.put("x1-y1-z1","test-test2-test3");
```

Now I have an input string array that contains some piece of the key:

```
String[] rem={"x","x1"}
```

Based on this string array I want to remove HashMap values.

Can anyone give an efficient approach to do this operation?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand exactly what you're doing and what you're asking. Perhaps it's me, but could you clarify this question a bit?

Comment: Map map=new HashMap(); map.put("x-y-z","test-test1-test2");map.put("x1-y1-z1","test-test2-test3"); Now i have Input string array contains String[] rem={"x","x1"}.based on this String array.I want to remove hashmap values.

Comment: Are you open to other data structures? If you have a lot of entries there are other structures (say nested maps) that will make this operation substantially faster.

Comment: Reverted the question :-) Your comment makes the question a bit clearer - but do you want the *beginning* of the hashmap key to be compared with each element of the String, and delete the map value accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List remList = Arrays.asList(rem);
for (Iterator it = map.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String key = (String) it.next();
    String[] tokens = key.split("-");
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        String token = tokens[i];
        if (remList.contains(token)) {
            it.remove();
            break;
        }
     }
}
```

And an updated version with adding functionality based on your latest comment on this answer:

```
private static Map getMapWithDeletions(Map map, String[] rem) {
    Map pairs = new HashMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < rem.length; i++) {
        String keyValue = rem[i];
        String[] pair = keyValue.split("@", 2);
        if (pair.length == 2) {
            pairs.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
        }
    }
    Set remList = pairs.keySet();
    for (Iterator it = map.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String key = (String) it.next();
        String[] tokens = key.split("-");
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            String token = tokens[i];
            if (remList.contains(token)) {
                it.remove();
                pairs.remove(token);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    map.putAll(pairs);
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maria,How Can i do samething for adding if no key matches.

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit further?
Do you mean the following?
If rem contains a value, e.g. x2, than does not exist anywhere in the map key tokens, add an entry to the map with x2 as key? And if so, with what value?

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention that,originally this the String array i will get as input String a[]={4-A06-19@A06-test-test1,2-B30-19@B30-test3-test4}.This string array is key@value.for deleting i have HashMap,if i use above code it will work,but for adding HashMap not avilable to me.i have to construct key and value in Hashmap based on string array input.

Comment: Maria:thanks for code,i am thinking about error condition,by mistake if pair[1] having B-30 Instead of B30.above code will cause ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException .Is anyway to avoid this error.

Comment: String[] pair = keyValue.split("@", 2);
        if (pair.length == 2) {
            pairs.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
        }

I updated my answer appropriately too.

Comment: Maria,I dont understand why are you checking condition with @.Above code have problem when i split with -.suppose take this value B30-test3-test4(correct one).if i get key like B-30-test3-test4(wrong one),i want to convert b-30 to b30 otherwise it will insert incorrect value.

Comment: I don't know the exact business logic that you want to implement. Please, use this one as a general guide and add the extra checks that you want to enforce, similarly to the one I added for the existence of the "@" symbol for the key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited based on edited question.**

Loop through the keySet of the hashmap.  When you find a key that starts with x you are looking for remove it from the map.

Something like:

```
for(String[] key: map.keySet()){
   if(key.length>0 && x.equals(key[0])){
      map.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: For large maps this won't be particularly efficient, and it doesn't generalize if the partial-key is, say, `y`.

Comment: @Mark E true, but in the ideal case the data would not even be stored in this structure.

Comment: which is a much better answer contingent on the OP's constraints. It's also not clear that the keys are arrays.

Comment: I given only test data key could be anything let's say y.

Comment: If you want a match to any value of the key to cause removal you will have to check against each value in your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand you correctly, and you want to remove everything starting with 'x-' and 'x1-' from the map (but not 'x1111-', even though 'x1' is a prefix of 'x1111'), and efficiency is important, you might want to look at one of the implementations of [`NavigableMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), such as (for example) [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

`NavigableMaps` keep their entries in order (by natural key order, by default), and can be iterated over and searched very efficiently.

They also provide methods like `subMap`, which can produce another Map which contains those keys in a specified range. Importantly, *this returned Map is a live view*, which means operations on this map affect the original map too.

So:

```
NavigableMap<String,String> map = new TreeMap<String,String>(); 
// populate data
for (String prefixToDelete : rem) {
    // e.g. prefixToDelete = "x"
    String startOfRange = prefixToDelete + "-"; // e.g. x-
    String endOfRange = prefixToDelete + "`"; // e.g. x`; ` comes after - in sort order
    map.subMap(startOfRange, endOfRange).clear(); // MAGIC!
}
```

Assuming your map is large, `.subMap()` should be much faster than iterating over each Map entry (as a TreeMap uses a [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) for fast searching).

Comment: Cowan: No x should be anything ,it is 1 or y or z and i am not comparing with x- ,i have to compare only with x.

Comment: OK, got you. Your example wasn't so clear, sorry. So using your example above (4-A06-19@A06-test-test1,2-B30-19@B30-test3-test4) then rem = {"B"} would remove the second one, or rem = {"0"} would remove both? In that case, my solution won't help, and you need to iterate in the style of Maria's answer. This is not especially efficient but as long as this is your problem scope I think you're stuck with inefficency.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```java
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
map.put("x-y-z","test-test1-test2");
map.put("x1-y1-z1","test-test2-test3"); 

String[] rem={"x","x1"};

for (String s : rem) {
    map.keySet().removeIf(key -> key.contains(s));
}
```

This piece of code will remove all entries with "x" or "x1" in the map key.